# Scheduled Powershell Script wont run

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a ps1 script like below, it filters files and outputs a formatted HTML file.

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:peachpuff;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PaleGoldenrod}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$b = Get-Date -Format u    

Get-ChildItem -Recurse K:\AppData\*.* -Filter *.CATPart | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} | sort LastWriteTime -descending | select name,LastWriteTime,Directory | convertto-html -head $a -body "<H2>CATIA PAST 7 DAYS -- $b </H2>" | out-file C:\aaa\catia_result.htm
```

I can run this script manually with no problem at all. but when I schedule it to run, it only gives me the formatted htm file without any filtered data in there.  This is arguments I used in task scheduler:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\aaa\RLTP_HTML_FINAL.ps1"
```

I tried change `executionpolicy` to `Unrestricted`, it still wont work. The task history shows the task completed, but there is no data in the HTML file.

I also tried to use a batch file call up powershell to run the script, it is the same result that it only works with manual operation but task scheduler.

Comment: You're trying to write to the root ``c:\`` folder. Are you sure you have write permission to do so?

Comment: Sorry, that is just an example here...I will change it

Comment: What if you use -File instead of -Command?

Comment: Tried -file , it wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, when you schedule the script to execute, it may not have a mapping to the `K:\` drive. Make sure that:

1. The K drive is mapped in the script, using the `Get-PSDrive` cmdlet
2. Your credentials that the scheduled task is set to use have access to the `K:\` drive

*Alternatively*, you could simply specify a UNC path, instead of referencing the `K:\` drive.

ps. Good job using `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`. That helps to avoid any issues with the execution policy! :) It doesn't matter what the execution policy is set to, as long as you use that parameter.

If you want to capture any errors in your script, make this your last line:

```
Add-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\error.log -Value $error;
```

You might see something about the `K:\` drive missing.

Comment: yes, drive mapping, never think about that, I will try it .thanks alot

Comment: Ha, It could not work because of drive mapping , thanks alot , really helps.

Comment: @user3303155: Glad to hear it!